# How to escape all special characters in a string (along with single and double quotes)?

Tags: perl

E.g:

```
$myVar="this#@#!~`%^&*()[]}{;'".,<>?/\";
```

I am not able to export this variable and use it as it is in my program.

Comment: `\Q\E` check these escape modifiers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [q](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) to store the characters and use the [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) to escape the all character

```
my $myVar=q("this#@#!~`%^&*()[]}{;'".,<>?/\");
$myVar = quotemeta($myVar);

print $myVar;
```

Or else use regex substitution to escape the all character

```
my $myVar=q("this#@#!~`%^&*()[]}{;'".,<>?/\");
$myVar =~s/(\W)/\\$1/g;
print $myVar;
```

Comment: $var=q($var);
   $var = quotemeta($var); In this its also escaping $ in '$var' so its not replacing value of $var ?

Comment: @PradnyaDeshmukh Instead use `qq($var);`

Answer (score 5):

This is what [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) is for, if I understand your quest

> Returns the value of EXPR with all non-"word" characters backslashed. (That is, all characters not matching `/[A-Za-z_0-9]/` will be preceded by a backslash in the returned string, regardless of any locale settings.) This is the internal function implementing the `\Q` escape in double-quoted strings.

Its use is very simple

```
my $myVar = q(this#@#!~`%^&*()[]}{;'".,<>?/\\);
print "$myVar\n";

my $quoted_var = quotemeta $myVar;
print "$quoted_var\n";
```

Note that we *must* manually *escape the last backslash*, to prevent it from escaping the closing delimiter. Or you can tack on an extra space at the end, and then strip it (by [chop](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chop.html)).

```
my $myVar = q(this#@#!~`%^&*()[]}{;'".,<>?/\ );
chop $myVar;
```

Now transform `$myVar` like above, using `quotemeta`.

I take the outside pair of `"` to merely indicate what you'd like in the variable. But if they are in fact meant to be in the variable then simply put it all inside `q()`, since then the last character is `"`.  The only problem is a backslash immediately preceding the closing delimiter.

If you need this in a regex context then you use `\Q` to start and `\E` to end escaping.

Answer (score 1):

[Giving Thanks to](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=468052):

What's between \Q and \E is treated as normal characters, not regexp characters. For example,

```
 '.' =~ /./;      # match
 'a' =~ /./;      # match
 '.' =~ /\Q.\E/;  # match
 'a' =~ /\Q.\E/;  # no match
```

It doesn't stop variables from being interpolated.

```
 $search = '.';
 '.' =~ /$search/;      # match
 'a' =~ /$search/;      # match
 '.' =~ /\Q$search\E/;  # match
 'a' =~ /\Q$search\E/;  # no match
```